# Xamarin after running/execution is not opening the page which i have created

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Xamarin after running/execution is not opening the page which i have created.
Do I need to change any thing in any file ?[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: please do NOT post code as an image!!!

Comment: Images I posted to show the settings of the visual studio. emulator mode -AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova

Comment: Try to execute the debugger again. Sometimes the virtual machine doesn't link well with visual studio, in particular when you open it not using the debugger itself. I advice you on trying the application using a real device if you have one because it's more quick than a virtual smartphone